# What can we say about the probability of two events when $A$ implies event $B$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have two events $A$ and $B$ where $A$ implies $B$. What can we say about their probabilities?

My try:

I can come up with two events

$A=\{\text{rainy weather}\}$

and

$B=\{\text{cloudy weather}\}$

where $A \rightarrow B$.

Also, we all know intuitively $\Pr\{\text{rainy weather}\}  \leq \Pr\{\text{cloudy weather}\}$.

Can you prove my argument rigorously using probability laws? I do not want showing this fact by words.

Comment: Try thinking of the implication in terms of an intersection between some events.

Comment: @Pratik Apshinge: please help me with that if you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\Rightarrow B$ means that $A\subseteq B$

this is the situation of $A\Rightarrow B$

[image]

- if A is true, B is true
- if B is true, A can be true or false.

Then, it is trivial that also $\mathbb{P}[A] \leq \mathbb{P}[B]$

Comment: but according to the Venn diagram you have, when $A$ is true, only $A\cap B$ is true not whole $B$. How would you justify that?

Comment: When A is true B must not be whole true....the truth of A is sufficient but not necessary for the truth of B. This is exactly the meaning of implication

Answer (score 1):

For "event $A$ implies event $B$", that means whenever event $A$ occurs, then event $B$ occurs. So by definition of subset, $A \subseteq B$. Intuitively, the set of outcomes in $B$ is at least as big as the set of outcomes in $A$.

By basic set theory results, $B = (A \cap B) \sqcup (B \setminus A) = A \sqcup (B \setminus A)$. ($\sqcup$ is disjoint union)

By probability axioms, $P(B) = P(A) + P(B \setminus A)$ and $P(B \setminus A) \ge 0$, so $P(A) \le P(B)$.